# Dropdown values disappear in an AJAX-based jQuery element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am growing quite fond using AJAX, JSON, and jQuery.  I am coding from scratch an application to replace a previous application that is flawed.

Although I am progressing and getting better using the AJAX method, I am coming across various issues that I want to correct, so that my replacement application is flawless.

My application uses AJAX to call PHP scripts.  It returns JSON that I use to populate certain dropdowns for the user to select.

For the most part, the application does what it is supposed to do.  The many dropdowns populate with the parsed JSON data.  The user can select 1 or more dropdowns which will then fire a SEARCH query that will return data.

The issue appears to happen when the data-set from the previous search is large.  I'm talking barely thousands.  When I click on the dropdown to conduct a new search, the dropdown (that was previously populating the JSON data) is now blank.

It doesn't do it all the time.  It seems this issue arises when the initial search returns a large data set.  I cannot be for sure.

Here is the html within my file called bpSearch.php: (just two of my dropdowns)

```
 <div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon">Sales Rep</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="salesRep" name="salesRep">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>                                                   
 </div>

 <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Services</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="service" name="service">
        <option value=""></option>                                                      
    </select>
 </div>
```

There are a few more dropdowns.  I only listed 2.

Here is the javascript (also within the same file, bpSearch.php) that populates the dropdowns via AJAX and JSON:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 // populates the dropdown id #salesRep
 $.getJSON( "api/reps.php", function( data ) 
 {
   $.each(data, function(index, item)
   {
     $('<option>').
       attr('value', item.fullname).
       text(item.fullname).
       appendTo($('#salesRep'));
   });
 });

 // populates the dropdown id #service
 $.getJSON( "api/services.php", function( data )
 {
   $.each(data, function(index, item)
   {
     $('<option>').
       attr('value', item.service).
       text(item.service).
       appendTo($('#service'));
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Here is the PHP called reps.php.  This returns the JSON data for the #service dropdown:

```
 <?php

   if ($result = 
         mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT DISTINCT(service) 
                       FROM services_imp ORDER BY service")) 
   {
     $out = array();
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {
       $out[] = $row;
     }

     echo json_encode($out);

     mysqli_free_result($result);
   }
 ?>
```

At this point, I don't think I need to show the code for reps.php.  It pretty much looks exactly the same as the code for services.php, except of course for the names of the fields that I search in the query.

With all the code above, I can populate the dropdowns as stated.  But, as I also previously stated, sometimes the dropdown values disappear after conducting a search.  This seems to always happen when the data-set is large.

Here is what the services dropdown looks like when it is working:

[image]

And here is what it looks like after I conduct a search that returns a larger data-set:

[image]

I do not understand why this is happening. What might be causing it?

Comment: I'd put a `console.log(data);` inside your `getJSON` call to see if your PHP script is return something or nothing.

Comment: You do know that AJAX is asynchronous. Large data-sets take time to build on the server (Query and returning the data as JSON through the while). As long as the AJAX call isn't completed the drop down will be empty.

Comment: @dan-klasson would you please show me where console.log(data) would go in detail?  I just want to make sure I get the syntax correct.  Thank you.

Comment: Also note that you are appending data to the DOM in your loop. If there really are a lot of items, you might want to build a string that you append after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to ensure that the dropdowns are loaded in DOM ready event

```
$(function()
{
   //AJAX call for loading dropdowns
})
```

Please make sure first that the calls are made in DOM ready event.

Comment: This is basically saying what Mouser said above.  Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The following code disables the dropdown when the AJAX function is called and enables it when the data is fully loaded. Execution starts when the page is fully loaded and I reduced your AJAX calls to one generic function that accepts an element and a uri as input. This function also makes a clone of the select. Appending the new options in memory and when the list is build the original select is replaced with the cloned one. This should enhance the browser performance.

```
function loadDataAndAppendToSelect(select, uri)
{
    $(select).prop('disabled', true); //disable
    // populates the dropdown id
     $.getJSON( uri, function( data ) 
     {
       var tempElement = $(select).clone();
       $.each(data, function(index, item)
       {
         $('<option>').
           attr('value', item.fullname).
           text(item.fullname).
           appendTo(tempElement);
       });
       $(select).replaceWith(tempElement);
       $(select).prop('disabled', false); //enable
     });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadDataAndAppendToSelect('#salesRep', 'api/reps.php');
    loadDataAndAppendToSelect('#service', 'api/services.php');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Mouser.  I will attempt this and get back to you.  It definitely looks promising.

Comment: I attempted the code, but all it does is leave those 2 dropdowns  disabled.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you outcomment the disable lines?

Comment: @Mouser you put disabled twice, i tried to corrected but you revert it back

Comment: @AhmedDaou Improved code removes disabled from object.

Comment: oh I see what you mean

Comment: jQuery is stupid. While `removeAttribute("disabled")` does what you expect in plain JavaScript `removeProp('disabled')` does not. Updated it.

Comment: @Mouser, I think this is working...  Using the exact code you gave me above, I am able to populate the dropdown for #salesRep, but not for #service.  I hope you get this.  Please let me know what you think.